# .pyc file gets created when it is not even imported

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have 2 Python files called `numbers.py` and `numpyBasicOps.py`.  `numbers.py` is a simple Python file, not importing any module. `numpyBasicOps.py` imports the `numpy` library.

Whenever I run `numpyBasicOps.py`, `numbers.py`'s output is displayed first followed by some error relating to `numpy` module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./numpyBasicOps.py", line 3, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.2rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.2rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.2rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.2rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.2rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import _internal  # for freeze programs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.2rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/numpy/core/_internal.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .numerictypes import object_
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.2rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/numpy/core/numerictypes.py", line 962, in <module>
    _register_types()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.2rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/numpy/core/numerictypes.py", line 958, in _register_types
    numbers.Integral.register(integer)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Integral'
```

Also, I see a `.pyc` file for `numbers.py` being generated.

How does the `numbers.pyc` file get generated even when it is not imported in `numpyBasicOps.py` and why is output for `numbers.py` displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy` registers their own integer-like objects as implementing the Abstract Base Class [`numbers.Integral`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html#numbers.Integral). To do this, it must use `import numbers` to get access to that object.

Or at least, it tried to and failed; as you named your module `numbers` *as well* it was imported instead. In other words, your `numbers.py` module masked the built-in [standard library module `numbers`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html).

Rename your module to something else, and make sure you delete the `numbers.pyc` file that was created.

Comment: Thank you @Martijn Pieters. It worked for me now. But I have a doubt: The numpy which I am currently having is newly installed. Earlier, the numpy was already present in Python. I did not have to install it separately. But for installing Tensorflow, this numpy version was giving problems so I had to delete it. I installed another version of numpy compatible to tensorflow. So, my doubt is - with earlier version of numpy, the file 'numpyBasicOps.py' used to work properly, without giving any numpy error. So why was it working earlier ?

Comment: @AnujaP: That's not much information to go on, but at a guess that sounds like the older version of `numpy` did not import `numbers`.